# Adding helper module to Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I would like to add a module that includes a method to help me log in as a user. Here it is:

```
module TestHelper
  require 'spec_helper'

  ALL_USERS = ["administrator", "instructor", "regular_user"]

  def self.login_as(user_type)
    user = User.find_by(global_role_id: GlobalRole.send(user_type))
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

The spec that's calling it is

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe QuestionsController, :type => :controller do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include TestHelper

  describe "a test" do
    it "works!" do
      TestHelper.login_as("administrator")
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the spec_helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TestHelper, :type => :controller
```

The error I get is: `undefined method 'env' for nil:NilClass` It looks like my module doesn't have access to `@request`.

My question is: how do I access and `@request` in the external Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `@request` in to `TestHelper.login_as` from the tests. Eg

```
module TestHelper
  def self.login_as(user_type, request)
    ...
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    ...
  end
end

...

describe 'log in' do
  it 'works!' do
    TestHelper.login_as('administrator', @request)
  end
end
```

But probably better to follow the macro pattern from the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)) if other devise mappings in play.

Comment: After some more exploration I found that the code needs to be wrapped in a before block. For reasons I don't understand it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Can you post an example of how it is now and how it was before adding it to before block? Whatever's accessible from the `before` block should be available within `it` example blocks as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, you should consider only including this module for relevant spec types using the following code:

```
config.include TestHelper, type: :controller  #  Or whatever spec type(s) you're using
```